# Вызов процедур из процедуры в Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Пытаюсь создать процедуру, которая вызывает другие процедуры. Но при попытке создать появляется ошибка о неправильном синтаксисе. Что я делаю не так? Все вызываемые процедуры созданы, параметры входные соответствуют принимаемым.
Тело процедуры:

```
CALL create_player_main(login, pass, email);
CALL create_player_params(login);
CALL create_player_realty(login);
CALL create_player_fraction(login);
CALL create_player_guild(login);
```

[image: Создаваемая процедура]
[image: Остальные вызываемые процедуры]
[image: текст ошибки]

Comment: Как минимум отсутствуют begin и end

Comment: @Mike, и правда отсутствуют, не знал. То есть, если делать больше одной операции в процедуре, то следует  писать begin, end?

Comment: да, именно так.